C++ a single place to keep all #includes?
Gets a bit complicated with all #includes within each CPP file, is there a single place to keep all #includes?

.h/header file?

You can create a "god header" with all the includes and then just include that one everywhere. While that "works" it will really hurt your compile times and please note that I do not recommend actually doing this. Is it really that much of a deal to include a few headers where you need them?

You can create a single header file that includes all the libraries and call that header in the respective code file, though this is a very bad practice and can cause circular dependency issues in case you're writing OOP code.
#includes specifies all the dependencies your code has, also it makes your code more understandable. Consider this: If I as developer am working on a code that someone else wrote it'd be easier for me to look at the libraries being used in that code instead of tracing header files that contains the libraries/dependencies and waste alot of time figuring out.
